# Passing config options via shell variable to git clone

Tags: git, bash, shell, environment-variables

I'm trying to pass dynamically created configuration options to `git clone` via an environment variable on bash.

Passing them directly works, but it does not work via the env variable:

```
$ git clone -c 'url.foo.insteadof=bar' git://git.cweiske.de/psist.git
... all fine

$ export PARAMS="-c 'url.foo.insteadof=bar'"; git clone $PARAMS git://git.cweiske.de/psist.git
error: invalid key: 'url.foo.insteadof
```

What can I do to make git recognize the options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in the first example the [quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) are syntactic:

```
$ (set -o xtrace; git clone -c 'url.foo.insteadof=bar' git://invalid) 2>&1 | grep 'git clone'
+ git clone -c url.foo.insteadof=bar git://invalid
```

while in the second they are literal:

```
$ (set -o xtrace; export PARAMS="-c 'url.foo.insteadof=bar'" && git clone $PARAMS git://invalid) 2>&1 | grep 'git clone'
+ git clone -c ''\''url.foo.insteadof=bar'\''' git://invalid
```

You can [use arrays to reliably pass arguments using variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time):

```
$ (set -o xtrace; export PARAMS=('-c' 'url.foo.insteadof=bar') && git clone "${PARAMS[@]}" git://invalid) 2>&1 | grep 'git clone'
+ git clone -c url.foo.insteadof=bar git://invalid
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use eval to get the parameters passed correctly.

```
export PARAMS="-c 'url.foo.insteadof=bar'"; 
eval git clone $PARAMS git://git.cweiske.de/psist.git
```